# Get data from geolocation in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variables, global

I am working on a geolocation script, but I can't get the content of my function.

Is there someone who can help me?

The code look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myvalue1;
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function()
{
    myvalue1 = 'test';
    window.myvalue2 = 'demo';
});

console.log(myvalue1);
console.log(window.myvalue2);
</script>
```

Both returns undefined and I simple don't know how to pull the data.

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its an asynchronous call. `console.log(myvalue1);` this line gets called before the `myvalue1='test'` which gets called only when user allows to share the permission. Since, `myvalue1` was `undefined` initially ,it reflects the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is asynchronous call. Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myvalue1;
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function()
{
    myvalue1 = 'test';
    window.myvalue2 = 'demo';
    console.log(myvalue1);
    console.log(window.myvalue2);
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your getCurrentPosition is not being called. Place it inside The document ready event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var coords;

function outputPosition()
{
    console.log('(' + coords.latitude + ', ' + coords.longitude + ')');
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position)
{
    coords = position.coords;
    outputPosition();
});

/*
    coords will still be undefined here because the callback function
    for getCurrentPosition has not been called yet.
*/

</script>
```

Comment: Yes I know that. The issue is that I really need the information outside the function.

Comment: I updated my code. `coords` won't be assigned until the callback is called asynchronously. You can access the information outside the function by calling another function.

Comment: Yes I can make a nice solution with this way of making the functions. Thanks :D